# SVN unresponsive

Tags: svn, osx-snow-leopard

i have been using svn for a while. Recently i started having errors when trying to update my code, or commit or checkout. All commands gives me errors. The svn update gives me the following error:

```
svn: Can't connect to host 'XXxXxXx': Operation timed out
```

svn co gives me this error

```
svn: Can't connect to host 'XXxXxXx': Address already in use
```

or sometime the first error itself.
What should i do? i did not change any settings. I am using Mac OS X snow leopard.
I am unable to ping the host.
Please also let me know if i need to give extra details.

Comment: being unable to ping the host suggests that this is a connectivity problem, not a subversion-specific problem.  Can you access any other services on the machine?  Have you verified that the remote server is in fact operating correctly?

Comment: i can checkout, update codes from another machine...

Comment: Can you tell us more about the setup you are using?  This could be a million different things.

Comment: i have a gateway server that is in the same network as the svn server. my friend can access the svn server and for me this problem occured just a couple of days ago.

Comment: This is probably a network issue, which makes me think it's mostly offtopic for stackoverflow.

Comment: how can this be a network issue when my friends laptop connects without a problem? i mean he is also in the same network..

Comment: I was having similar issues on our company network.  I switched wifi networks to one that had better connectivity, and svn started working.  So yeah, it's probably a network issue.  Did you try connecting to a different router/switch/hub/wifi?  There must be something different between your setup and your friend's.  Finding out what's different isn't always simple.  Good luck!